# PHP working with different database implementations

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, vertica

Thanks for taking an interest in this post, basically I'm looking for some advice on working with data from different database implementations within PHP, or if PHP isn't suitable for these tasks, any recommendations regarding other approaches.

The task I would like to accomplish can be illustrated with the following example. I have a MySQL database where I store demographic information regarding users organised by user_id on 'server A', this runs to about 200,000 rows. On server B, I have users usage data stored by user_id and event_id in a Vertica database that runs to about 300,000,000 rows.

I would like to find a way to join these datasets so I can produced summarised output consisting of aggregated user events taken from the Vertica database grouped by data contained in the MySQL database such as age and location, through a join on the 'user_id' field.

I realise that this could be accomplished by creating a copy of either of these tables on the other server but I'm curious if this can be achieved without it.

My questions are:

- Can PHP do operations like this? if so a link to an example would be really welcome.
- Do you need to load the data into arrays and join there? Can you join arrays in PHP like tables in a database? Can PHP handle large arrays like this?
- Are there any other approaches that I should be considering instead?

Thanks in advance for any help,

James

Comment: Are you using CPanel by any chance. There is a remote MySQL option in the admin and you can basically connect to different MySQL servers after white listing the IP Address in Remote MySQL

Comment: Hi Sandeep, thanks for the comment. I'm not currently using CPanel although there's no reason why I couldn't. Would this also facilitate connecting to Vertica?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using TALEND ! is an open source ETL tool that has Mysql and Vertica connector implemented into it. 
 You can aggregate data sets from any rdbms as long as TALEND has access to them ! and then dump them where you need. 
Give it a try .